# Flutter and Firebase Google SignIn

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-signin

I'm trying to make an app with Firebase/Google SignIn to manage Drive Files. 
To do this, I'm using the plugin `google_sign_in: "^ 3.2.1"` of the flutter. My app show's user account select - by Google's, but nothing happen when I tap on account... Debugging the method of googlesignin I've found a message "the user had canceled the process" or similar.

I tried this step-by-step
  - https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in

I'm using:

- Physical Test Device Flutter (Channel beta, v0.9.4, on Linux, locale
  pt_BR.UTF-8)
- develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
- Android Studio (version 3.2)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was occurred because I used a release key instead a debug on firebase console configurations.